# MethodHandle example throws WrongMethodTypeException on invokeExact call

Tags: java, jvm, java-7, invokedynamic, methodhandle

The example shown in the description of the `MethodHandle` class throws a `WrongMethodTypeException` in the invocation of the statement `mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n')` with the following description: `(CC)Ljava/lang/String; cannot be called with a different arity as ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;`.

The `MethodHandle` object `mh` has a symbolic type descriptor corresponding to: `(CC)Ljava/lang/String`. But when we are invoking `mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n')`, the arguments: `d` and `n` are passed as an `Object` array and then they are not matching with the arguments of the type `char`.

I know that I can resolve the above problem using the `invokeWithArguments` instead of the `invokeExcat` or the `invoke`, but this example was supposed to work as presented in the description of the `MethodHandle` of Java 7 API. Besides that, the `invokeWithArguments` has a performance overhead in relation to `invoke`/`invokeExact`.

Answer (score 2):

How are you compiling this?

It sounds suspiciously like a known Eclipse bug to me.

I've just checked with javac and this code:

```
import java.lang.invoke.*;

public class ScratchMH {    
        private static ScratchMH instance = null;

        public ScratchMH() {
                super();
        }

        private void run() throws Throwable {
                Object x, y; String s; int i;
                MethodType mt; MethodHandle mh;
                MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();

                // mt is (char,char)String
                mt = MethodType.methodType(String.class, char.class, char.class);
                mh = lookup.findVirtual(String.class, "replace", mt);
                s = (String) mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n');
                // invokeExact(Ljava/lang/String;CC)Ljava/lang/String;

                System.out.println(s);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
                instance = new ScratchMH();
                instance.run();
        }
}
```

seems to work OK:

```
ariel-2:src boxcat$ javac scratch/clj/ScratchMH.java 
ariel-2:src boxcat$ java scratch/clj/ScratchMH
nanny
ariel-2:src boxcat$
```

The relevant portion of output from javap seems sane as well:

```
  35: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual:(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  38: astore        6
  40: aload         6
  42: ldc           #9                  // String daddy
  44: bipush        100
  46: bipush        110
  48: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.invokeExact:(Ljava/lang/String;CC)Ljava/lang/String;
  51: astore_3
```

Comment: Seeing this bug too with OpenJDK 1.7.0_07 on linux with the code [of this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146570/calling-a-getter-in-java-though-reflection-whats-the-fastest-way-to-repeatedly)

Answer (score 0):

`invokeExact` requires exact match between the MH's method type description, and the types of arguments. Since the MH's method type is `(cc)string`, so what you want to execute the MH, both the first and second argument should be char. Thus, it is like that

```
``String s = (String)mh.invokeExact('a', 'b')``
```