# How much performance decrease if I implement a java class' accessors using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Regardless if it is a good or bad OO practice to provide accessors in a class, I'd like to know if executing access to a specific attribute of an object via reflection decrease performance (memory consumption or cpu time).

Have you implemented this and performed a benchmark?
Do you know about anyone who has performed such benchmark?

Edit:

Due to some comments which indicates that it's **obvious** that performance decrease I've modified the title of the question to indicates that I'd like to know how bad is the impact of implementing accessors with reflection.

Edit:

Thank you for your kind comments and answers. Based on the answer from @Peter Lawrey and the kind comment from @EJP, this is what I meant and wanted to know if any of you have implemented prior to my question:

```
package co.com.prueba.reflection;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class A {

private String s;


public void setS(String s){
    this.s=s;
}

public String getS(){
    return this.s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {

    System.out.println("Invoking .setAccesible(true) ...");
    A secondA = new A();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Field f = secondA.getClass().getDeclaredField("s");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.get(secondA);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start));
    }

    System.out.println("Without invoking .setAccesible(true) ...");
    A firstA = new A();     
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Field f = firstA.getClass().getDeclaredField("s");          
        f.get(firstA);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start));
    }

    System.out.println("Invoking the getter ...");
    A thirdA = new A();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        thirdA.getS();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start));
    }


}
```

}

Here are the results:

[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: Reflection is always slow.

Comment: Of course it's slower and heavyer than just accessing the variable. And it brings many other problems, like the fact you're compilation doesn't verify the coherency of the accesses.

Comment: What do you mean exactly, accessors (getters and setters) are not reflection.

Comment: Please show us some example code, so that we know *exactly* what you mean.

Comment: Two basic laws of *using reflection* : 1. The programmer always thinks it's cool. 2. I's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I don't see how this question could be answered in a constructive way. Any benchmark would be specific.

Comment: Sorry @dystroy. I don't get your last comment Why does any benchmark would be specific?

Comment: A benchmark is specific to a specific test. That's why it can't be a definite answer to a (much too) wide question.

Comment: @SLaks When warmed up a getter can take about 3 ns via reflection which may not be as slow as your thought. ;)

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't have measured this for yourself on your own target hardware rather than starting an open ended discussion.

Comment: If you only take the first <10,000 calls this is before you have warmed up the code (it is not even compiled to native code at this point) I suggest you run the test for at least 2 seconds to ensure it is warmed up enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a typical machine the cost of calling a getter via reflection is about 3 ns. A setter is much the same.  As a getter can be inlined or even eliminated without reflection there is a high relative difference.

How much difference will 3 ns make to you?

I have supplied a code example and results in my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146641/57695) yesterday. ;)

Comment: @assylias Allot but not to the same extent a direct call will. Before the code has warmed up, the cost is closer to 500 ns if you use setAccessible(true) and 1500 ns if you don't)

Comment: @PeterLawrey this was the base for my implementation. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get just the minimal performance hit that others talk about, be sure to understand that this involves **only** the reflective call on an already existing `Method` object. If you do the lookup in every call, the performance hit is **huge**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance) answers your question on performance in general. And hope this [blog](http://buzdin.blogspot.com/2011/01/is-java-reflection-really-slow.html) will help you to get some info. on benchmark values. It has some external links such as posts from IBM - [Reflection performance benchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=13862806). which discuss about benchmark values.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Reflection Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance)

It is better than it used to be (I think prior to 1.4) but is still slower than accessing variable directly.  I believe it is due to having to load the class and all attributes into memory and then search the list for the one you want.

Accessing a variable directly is recommended (or atleast was) by Google when doing android development to cut out the virtual method call.