# How can I create a Functional interface implementation for Fields?

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

Consider a field `weight` in class `Animal`. I want to be able to create a *getter* and *setter* functional interface objects for manipulating this field.

```
class Animal {
  int weight;
}
```

My current approach is similar to one used for methods:

```
public static Supplier getter(Object obj, Class<?> cls, Field f) throws Exception {
  boolean isstatic = Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers());
  MethodType sSig = MethodType.methodType(f.getType());
  Class<?> dCls = Supplier.class;
  MethodType dSig = MethodType.methodType(Object.class);
  String dMthd = "get";
  MethodType dType = isstatic? MethodType.methodType(dCls) : MethodType.methodType(dCls, cls);
  MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
  MethodHandle fctry = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, dMthd, dType, dSig, lookup.unreflectGetter(f), sSig).getTarget();
  fctry = !isstatic && obj!=null? fctry.bindTo(obj) : fctry;
  return (Supplier)fctry.invoke();
}
```

But this gives the following error:

```
java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Unsupported MethodHandle kind: getField x.Animal.weight:()int
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying to create a class `ObjectMap` implementing `interface Map`, which basically tries to **represent** an *object* as a `Map`, where the *object* can be of **any** type. Was currently using `Field.get()` and `Field.set()` for manipulating fields in `get()` and `put()` methods, and using above mentioned approach to create `Supplier` and `Consumer` objects for invoking *getter* and *setter* methods. I was wondering if i could merge the two separate methods into one.

Example class which could be used as a `Map` through `ObjectMap`:

```
public class ThisCanBeAnything {
  /* fields */
  public String normalField;
  private int hiddenFiled;
  private String hiddenReadonlyField;

  /* getters and setters */
  public int hiddenField() {
    return hiddenField;
  }
  public void hiddenField(int v) {
    System.out.println("set: hiddenField="+v);
    hiddenField = v;
  }

  public String hiddenReadonlyField() {
    return hiddenReadonlyField;
  }
}
```

And here is the expected usage:

```
Object o = new ThisCanBeAnything();
Map m = new ObjectMap(o);
m.put("normalField", "Normal");
System.out.println(m.get("normalField")); // Normal
m.put("hiddenField", 1); // set: hiddenField=1
System.out.println(m.get("hiddenField")); // 1
m.put("hiddenReadonlyField", 1); // does not do anything
System.out.println(m.get("hiddenReadonlyField")); // null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly write the lambda, you don't need the `LambdaMetafactory` at all:

```
public static Supplier getter(Object obj, Field f) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            return f.get(obj);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Or a runtime-typesafe version:

```
public static <T> Supplier<T> getter(Object obj, Class<T> fieldClass, Field f) {

    if (!fieldClass.isAssignableFrom(f.getType()))
        throw new RuntimeException("Field is not of expected type");

    return () -> {
        try {
            return (T) f.get(obj);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

e.g.:

```
private class X {
    public int a;
}

@Test
public void supplier_getter_test() throws NoSuchFieldException {
    X a = new X();
    a.a = 5;

    Supplier<Integer> sup = getter(a, int.class, X.class.getField("a"));

    assertEquals(5, sup.get().intValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does solve my purpose, but you are still using reflection in `Field.get()`. In case of methods, i use the above approach to get an interface object that could be directly called. If a similar approach would be possible, it would be great.

Comment: Well that was your starting point, passing in `Field`. You didn't say how you got it. I don't understand your extra requirement from the comment.

Comment: I do need a supplier object but if it faster, it is better. So, was expecting a method that is faster than reflection.

Comment: I think you need a new question, with, if speed is really important, proof that `Field.get` is too slow, and more background information as it's feeling like a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Yes you are right, i am trying to create a class `ObjectMap` implementing `interface Map`, which basically tries to **represent** an object as a `Map`. Was currently using `Field.get()` and `Field.set()` for manipulating fields in `get()` and `put()` methods, and using above mentioned approach to create `Supplier` and `Consumer` objects for invoking *getter* and *setter* methods. I was wondering if i could merge the two separate methods into one. I now understand that i made it a bit vague.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the above logic, as i can use it to simplify the logic used in `get()` and `put()`.

Answer (score 5):

You are making it too difficult that it needs to be. When you have a `Field`, you can directly invoke [`unreflectGetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflectGetter-java.lang.reflect.Field-) on the lookup factory to retrieve a `MethodHandle`:

> Produces a method handle giving read access to a reflected field. The type of the method handle will have a return type of the field's value type. If the field is static, the method handle will take no arguments. Otherwise, its single argument will be the instance containing the field.

```
public static Supplier<Object> getter(Object obj, Class<?> cls, Field f) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    return () -> {
        try {
            MethodHandle handle = lookup.unreflectGetter(f);
            return Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) ? handle.invoke() : handle.invoke(obj);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(t);
        }
    };
}
```

This returns a supplier of the value of the field. Depending on the accessibility of the field, you might need to invoke [`setAccessible(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject:A-boolean-).

Note that method handles and the reflection API also differs [in terms of performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337726/1743880) and might be faster.

Comment: Thanks. From the performance answer you pointed to, `plain` is as fast as `static_unreflect_invokeExact`, but wierdly **non-final** ones are much slower.

Comment: Oh i just noticed that you are un-reflecting inside the lambda function, which could be slow.

Comment: @wolfram77 Yes, I think a benchmark would be needed to tell whether it is faster or not.

Answer (score 5):

Functional style lets you think about such things in new ways.  Instead of a reflection-based approach like

```
Supplier getter(Object obj, Class<?> cls, Field f){...}
```

try something like

```
static <O,F> Supplier<F> getter(O obj, Function<O,F> extractor) {
    return () -> extractor.apply(obj);
}
```

which you would invoke like

```
Supplier<Integer> getWeight = getter(animal, a -> a.weight);
Integer weight = getWeight.get();
```

Is `a -> a.weight` any harder than coming up with a `Field` via reflection?

One advantage is that you could use fields or methods as needed, e.g., if you added a getter for weight,

```
Supplier<Integer> getWeight = getter(animal, Animal::getWeight);
```

A similar setter factory might be

```
static <O,F> Consumer<F> setter(O obj, BiConsumer<O,F> modifier) {
    return field -> modifier.accept(obj,field);
}
```

Invoked like this

```
Consumer<Integer> setWeight = setter(animal, (a, w) -> a.weight = w);
setWeight.accept(90);
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. This is a good solution to the question i posted, but not what i really needed as the class is *dynamic* as i mentioned in an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t bind a `MethodHandle` bearing a direct access to a field to a function interface instance, but you can bind the accessor method of the `Field` instance:

```
public static Supplier getter(Object obj, Class<?> cls, Field f) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle get=lookup.findVirtual(Field.class,"get",MethodType.genericMethodType(1));
    MethodHandle fctry = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "get",
        get.type().changeReturnType(Supplier.class), MethodType.genericMethodType(0),
        get, MethodType.genericMethodType(0)).getTarget();
    return (Supplier)fctry.invoke(f, Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())? null: obj);
}
```

Though in this specific example you may consider generating an `IntSupplier` instead:

```
public static IntSupplier getter(Object obj, Class<?> cls, Field f) throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle get=lookup.findVirtual(Field.class, "getInt",
            MethodType.methodType(int.class, Object.class));
    MethodHandle fctry = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "getAsInt",
        get.type().changeReturnType(IntSupplier.class), MethodType.methodType(int.class),
        get, MethodType.methodType(int.class)).getTarget();
    return (IntSupplier)fctry.invoke(f, Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())? null: obj);
}
```

…

```
final Animal animal = new Animal();
IntSupplier s=getter(animal, Animal.class, Animal.class.getDeclaredField("weight"));
animal.weight=42;
System.out.println(s.getAsInt());
```

Comment: In the first example, are you trying to create a `Supplier` from the `Field.get()` function? I am not sure how exactly `LambdaMetaFactory` works, but this method seems similar to @weston answer where he too creates a `Supplier` using a lambda expression. However i learned this method from your [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557829/faster-alternatives-to-javas-reflection/19563000#19563000) (long back) that it is as fast as a direct function call, for using with methods.

Comment: It’s semantically equivalent, just saving one level of delegation and not bothering with the checked exception (which hasn’t any performance difference). So you may stay with weston’s solution, *both* have the advantage that from the JVM’s point of view, the `Field` and target object are kept within `final` fields of the generated class allowing an optimistic inlining. If you use this method multiple times with different `Field`s,my solution has the slight advantage of generating a new class for each `Field` so the type profiles stay clean,but it’s hard to predict whether it has a real benefit

Comment: Maybe a future version of `LambdaMetafactory` will support field handles but atm it’s the best we can get…

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer, but I have developed a library that you can use to turn any `MethodHandle` into a lambda function. The performance is the same as if you would manually implement the function with direct access.

The impl is based around the fact that static final `MethodHandle`s are being inlined to point of being as fast as direct access. More info on this can be found here:
[How can I improve performance of Field.set (perhap using MethodHandles)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244402/how-can-i-improve-performance-of-field-set-perhap-using-methodhandles?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The library can be found here: https://github.com/LanternPowered/Lmbda. For now you will have to use Jitpack to access it (small library so it won't take long to compile):
https://jitpack.io/#LanternPowered/Lmbda

An example for setting a field on a object:

```
import org.lanternpowered.lmbda.LmbdaFactory;
import org.lanternpowered.lmbda.LmbdaType;
import org.lanternpowered.lmbda.MethodHandlesX;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer;

public class LambdaSetterTest {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandlesX.privateLookupIn(TestObject.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
        final MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.findSetter(TestObject.class, "data", int.class);

        final ObjIntConsumer<TestObject> setter = LmbdaFactory.create(new LmbdaType<ObjIntConsumer<TestObject>>() {}, methodHandle);

        final TestObject object = new TestObject();
        System.out.println(100 == object.getData());
        setter.accept(object, 10000);
        System.out.println(10000 == object.getData());
    }

    public static class TestObject {

        private int data = 100;

        int getData() {
            return this.data;
        }
    }
}
```

And getting a field from a object:

```
import org.lanternpowered.lmbda.LmbdaFactory;
import org.lanternpowered.lmbda.LmbdaType;
import org.lanternpowered.lmbda.MethodHandlesX;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;

public class LambdaSetterTest {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandlesX.privateLookupIn(TestObject.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
        final MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.findGetter(TestObject.class, "data", int.class);

        final ToIntFunction<TestObject> getter = LmbdaFactory.create(new LmbdaType<ToIntFunction<TestObject>>() {}, methodHandle);

        final TestObject object = new TestObject();
        System.out.println(100 == getter.applyAsInt(object));
        object.setData(10000);
        System.out.println(10000 == getter.applyAsInt(object));
    }

    public static class TestObject {

        private int data = 100;

        void setData(int value) {
            this.data = value;
        }
    }
}
```