# Is there an equivalent of MethodHandle in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my project I need to dynamically access getters and setters of different objects many times. Due to that I would like a fast method for accessing a method dynamically.

Java 7 introduced the [MethodHandle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) class for dynamically executing a method of a given class. From what I can see there is no such thing on the Android port of the JDK. Is there any workaround that can be used to circumvent this, other than using the standard reflection classes?

Comment: "_other than using the standard reflection classes_" Why?

Comment: is it for simple getter/setters or something more complicated ?

Comment: @Unihedron my understanding is that a MethodHandle will be faster than standard reflection and for my needs I need a faster method than reflection. See here for a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146570/calling-a-getter-in-java-though-reflection-whats-the-fastest-way-to-repeatedly

Comment: @radai getters and setters would suffice, I edited my question so that ti is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could obviously just get the appropriate Method object and call it.

but if you want something faster you could generate a class at runtime that calls your target method. so you locate the method using normal reflection, generate a MethodCaller class that implements some interface that you define beforehand (callMethod() ?), load that newly generated class and use it. there's a library thats compatible with the android runtime [here](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) and a long discussion listing other possible alternatives [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6322).

while this is doable, its certainly not easy and i'd recommend trying normal reflection and measuring the performance. maybe it'll work well enough.

Comment: I feared something like that. I will look into that and see if I can manage to do what I want.

Comment: I managed to test the code, and even if it's a bit trickier it appears to be working. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `Method` won't let you call super methods directly (e.g. Method can't call `ListView#arrowScroll` from `MyListViewSubclass#arrowScroll`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems with API level 26 (Oreo 2017) method handles are also
part of the Android platform. They are useful to perform an invoke special.

This might be needed for reflective call of a default method from within a Proxy or simply do a reflective super call.

What I don't know yet whether some [lookup issues](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/274) have been fixed in Android.